# Multiple divs - Horizontal slide out content

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion, slidetoggle

I've been staring at my monitor all day perhaps too long where I'm making the problem too complicated when it's quite simple. Hoping somewhere here can slap me digitally and point me in the right direction.

Three elements floated left and positioned absolute within a container. On toggle of each element opens up to reveal sliderContent which is hidden by default. Once clicked the surrounded elements are pushed aside not overlapped.

Code:

```
<ul class="accordion">

<li class="item one">
    <div class="slideContent">
            Slider content
    </div>

</li>
<li class="item two">

     <div class="slideContent">
             Slider content
    </div>

</li>
<li class="item three">

     <div class="slideContent">
             Slider content
    </div>

</li>
```

```
 .accordion {
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
}


 .item {
    width:25%;
    height:200px;
    background:#ccc;
    z-index: 0;
    margin-top: 10px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

.slideContent {
    background:white;
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
 }

.one {
    background:black;
}
.two{
    background:green;
    left: 25%;
}
.three {
    background:blue;
    left:50%;
}
.four {
    left: 75%;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.slideContent').hide();


$('li.item').click(function(){
    $(this).css({zIndex: 9999}).animate({left:'0px', width: '100%'})
    $(this).$('.slideContent').show();
});
```

Fiddle thus far: http://jsfiddle.net/ywL5n4w9/2/

To help explain I've made a superb image.

[image]

Hopefully that makes sense, It may be gobbledegook and for that I blame 11 + cups of coffee.

Comment: Please don't try and remove the question once it's been solved to your satisfaction; the question should remain in order to help others facing a similar problem in the future. If an answer to your question has solved the problem please consider accepting that answer (check the check-mark to the left of the relevant answer), or if you solved the problem yourself please take the time to post your solution to your problem as an answer and accept that (though to accept your own answer you have to wait two days to do so).

Answer (score 2):

Your items are positioned absolutely, which roughly means that they loose their ability to influence other elements, which includes pushing them aside.

If you change your `.item` from `position:absolute` to `float:left` and also remove the `position:absolute` from the `.slideContent`, it seems to work.

New jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ywL5n4w9/1/)

Comment: Updated my post to hopefully make it more clear of what I am looking for.